# Deleting a line stored in a variable in Python

Tags: python, delete-file

The global variable `originalInfo` contains

```
Joe;Bloggs;j.bloggs@anemail.com;0715491874;1
```

I have written a function to delete that line in a text file containing more information of this type. It works, but it is really clunky and inelegant.

```
    f = open("input.txt",'r') # Input file
    t = open("output.txt", 'w') #Temp output file

    for line in f:
        if line != originalInfo: 
            t.write(line) 

    f.close()
    t.close()
    os.remove("input.txt")
    os.rename('output.txt', 'input.txt')
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: That looks okay in principle, however I doubt you will get matches because your `originalInfo` is lacking the newline character. I also suggest to use the context manager qualities of the file objects.

Comment: The only way to have an elegant function for this is to use a better file format in the first place.

Comment: This seems like a more appropriate job for `sed` if that option is available to you. `sed -i '/pattern to match/d' ./input.txt`

Comment: Didn't you [ask the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236242/appending-a-specific-line-after-having-found-it-in-python/36236469#36236469) a few hours ago?

Comment: Well I applied the same logic, i.e. creating a temporary file and only printing the lines that aren't the same as the one found. However I thought there must be a shorter, more concise solution when the line needs to be deleted, not modified.

Answer (score 0):

You solution nearly works, but you need to take care of the trailing newline. This is bit shorter version, doing what you intend:

```
import shutil

with open("input.txt",'r') as fin, open("output.txt", 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.strip() != originalInfo: 
            fout.write(line) 
shutil.move('output.txt', 'input.txt')
```

The `strip()` is a bit extra effort but would strip away extra white space.
Alternatively, you could do:

```
originalInfo += '\n'
```

and later in the loop:

```
if line != originalInfo:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file, read it by `readlines()`, close it and open it to write again. With this way you don't have to create an output file:

```
with open('input.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines

with open('input.txt') as file:
    for line in lines:
        if line != originalInfo:
            file.write(line)
```

But if you want to have an output:

```
with open('input.txt') as input:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
        for line in input:
            if line != originalInfo:
                output.write(line)
```